# MySQL - How to convert non-unique rows into columns and maintain integrity?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert this table into another table with the row of Bill Type being two distinct columns, one for Utilities and one for Overhead. I suspect I'd have to use a LIKE 'Utilities%' in there somewhere.

tbl_charges

```
House ID  Account  AC Type    Date          Bill Type       Amount
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1        A        20170101      Overhead           40.00
1        1        A        20170101      Utilities @ Elec   15.50
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2        1        B        20170101      Overhead           35.00
2        1        B        20170101      Utilities @ Elec   25.50
---------------------------------------------------------------------
3        2        B        20170101      Overhead           42.00
3        2        B        20170101      Utilities @ Water  18.25
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1        1        A        20170301      Overhead           39.00
1        1        A        20170301      Utilities @ Elec   19.50
---------------------------------------------------------------------
4        4        A        20170201      Overhead           55.00
4        4        A        20170201      Utilities @ Water  17.25
```

I want to combine the two House ID rows for any given Date and just have one row for that date with the Overhead in one column and the Utilities in another column. Essentially, I want just one row for any given House ID and Date. The output for House ID 1 on 20170101 row should look like this:

```
House ID  Account  AC Type    Date     Overhead  Utilities  Total Amount
1         1        A          20170101 40.00     15.50      55.50
```

Comment: How do you know which AC Type to use, for example with House ID = 4? Is the Account value always the same for each House ID? Otherwise you'll have the same issue there as well.

Comment: The accounts are tied to the House ID. For House ID 4, that is a typo. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: For House ID 1 on date 20170101, Overhead cost is 40.00, Utilities cost is 15.50. Therefore total cost is 40.00 + 15.50 = 55.50

Comment: @buttpee Yes i have to reformat the table I was confused and thought the dates were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT HouseId, Account, `AC Type`, Date, 
        MAX( CASE WHEN BillType = 'Overhead' THEN Amount END) as Overhead,
        MIN( CASE WHEN BillType LIKE  'Utilities%' THEN Amount END) as Utilities,
        SUM(Amount) as `Total Amount`
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY HouseId, Account, `AC Type`, Date
```

Comment: Running this query now. Might take a while, as the table has a couple million records. Will the SUM(Amount) give me the proper sum for a single House ID on a single date? It seems like it would just sum the whole column.

Comment: The sum will operate over the fields in your "GROUP BY" clause.

Comment: I see. It is a successful query, thank you. What is the reasoning for using MAX for Overhead and MIN for Utilities then?

Comment: Because I first thought you have multiple data from same group. Right now you can use MIN or MAX, because only one element match the conditional inside.